# How can I use a timer in a thread by C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

When I want to use a timer in a thread it gives an error like this:

```
Error   1   Method name expected
```

This my code:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = String.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss tt}", DateTime.Now);
        ParameterizedThreadStart th1 = new ParameterizedThreadStart(timer1_Tick(new object(),new EventArgs()));
        //ThreadStart th1 = new ThreadStart(test);
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = String.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss tt}", DateTime.Now);

    }
```

The error is occurring on this line:

```
ParameterizedThreadStart th1 = new ParameterizedThreadStart(timer1_Tick(new object(),new EventArgs()));
```

Comment: timer1_Tick is a event handler not a thread function. Also you cant change label1.Text from a thread you need to invoke the control

Comment: so what should i do for that? i should show the time on a label and it should be updated every second, but when do something in the program the time doesn't updated untill i finished my job

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Timers;

Label l;
private void updateClock(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    l.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
    {
        l.Text = String.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss tt}", DateTime.Now);
    }));

}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    l = new Label();
    l.Location = new Point(5, 5);
    this.Controls.Add(l);

    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Elapsed += updateClock;
    timer.Enabled = true;
    timer.AutoReset = true;
    timer.Interval = 1000;
    timer.Start();
}
```

This is how i imagine you wanted to do it.